# LAN / vLAN security implementation to allow limited internet access

Tags: networking, security, vlan

I am a programmer with limited knowledge of network administration so please bear with me.

In our office, we have two vLANs, vLAN10 and vLAN20

**WAN** > [**Router**] > [**Cisco Switch**] > [**vLAN10 and vLAN20**] > clients on vLAN10 and vLAN20

vLAN10 has access to internet whereas vLAN20 has no access to internet.
Both vLANs has access to a NAS (which as two Ethernet ports vLAN10, vLAN20) so clients on vLAN10 can access to NAS as well as Internet whereas clients on vLAN20 can access to NAS only.

We download file on a client on vLAN10, copy it to a Shared-Folder on NAS so clients on vLAN20 can access the downloaded file.

What security policies should we implement for the above?

Secondly, we need to allow clients on vLAN20 to have internet access but in a limited fashion, i.e. access to allowed websites only, email, ftp or other services should not be allowed to prevent them to send / upload files etc. over the internet,

Is this possible?
How to implement such policies?
Do we need buy some other hardware?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think need any security policy for the existing situation? It sounds like it pretty much does what you want, if the idea is to prevent the need for Internet access to the machines on vLAN20. Yes it's a 2 step process, but assuming sensible rules are in place for the users on vLAN10 so they know what files they should be downloading and exposing to the vLAN20 machines.

You haven't explained what the intent is of this policy, why you need to keep the machines on vLAN20 off the internet. Without out a clear understanding of what the threat model you are working with it's impossible to give a definitive answer.

Now assuming you have changed your mind and now want to allow some limited internet access for those machines, the simplest solution is to install a HTTP proxy on the NAS (assuming it's a Consumer/SOHO NAS e.g. Synology. QNAS) and make sure all the devices on vLAN20 are configured to use the proxy.

How you set up the rules on the Proxy will depend on the proxy, but I expect something like a Synology will supply Squid as it's proxy plugin. But you'll have to lock it down pretty hard to stop people being able to access web based email or file sharing sites, since most now offer access via HTTP specifically to get round people being stuck behind HTTP proxies.

It's worth understanding that with the right tools and a little thought it's possible to tunnel a full VPN via a HTTP proxy.

Comment: I'm using TrueNAS (can we protect it accessing from the internet?)
vLAN10 clients should be able to have full internet access.
vLAN20 clients should be able to have limited internet access, we don't want them to upload files, send emails including Gmail, FTP etc. only allow access to few websites only.

Comment: It's a small software house, vLAN20 is for interns and we don't want them to upload / send files via email / file sharing sites so, need to give access to few websites only

Comment: *to have limited internet access, we don't want them to upload files, send emails including Gmail, FTP etc. only allow access to few websites only* — that is harder than you expect. Which sites exactly? For instance, if you want them to be able access StackOverflow, you won't be able to filter out access to other HTTPS sites, because of DoH and HSTS preload.